# using vue-tailwind input, how to set default value for input after deleting all the content?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

as mentioned in the title i'm using vue-tailwind in my FE application.
using t-input, how can i set the placeholder within the input to zero after the user deletes the content of the input.

I have v-model attached to the input, the v-model captures and change the local state of my component.
the value that was captured then being used in one of my calculation. however, if the user removes the content within the input i have NAN which breaks my calculation.
any suggestion on how to overcome it while using the best practices?

```
<t-input
  v-model="placeholderVModel"
  class="text-center"
  :disabled="!placeHolderDisabled"
  type="number"
  :step="1"
  :min="placeHolderMinimum"
></t-input>
```

Comment: what calculation?  could just adding an if statement checking for NaN before using the value prevent the issue?  "placeholder" is also probably the wrong word.  literal [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/placeholder) which t-input supports does not influence the actual **value** of an input.  You need to be checking your v-model.  For example, on the element's `change` event if v-model is empty string, set to 0.